# Delete set of folders contain more than one '-' in different places as a part of their name

Tags: directory, delete, file-management

How can I delete many folders that have more than one `-` in their names?

For example:

```
e97bf913-5759-4fff-bdaf-2f931b53a432/
39f953c5-dab0-420e-a650-a50a30f48097/
```

Comment: Do you want "more than one time" or "exactly 4 times"? What if there are 3 `-` or 5? And will they all be in the same directory or do you need to recurse into subdirectories?

Comment: More than one, the same directory only @terdon

Comment: Those are [version 4 UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). You might want to use a pattern that specifically matches such UUIDs, rather than anything with multiple hyphens in the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern

```
*-*-*/
```

matches directories with two or more hyphens. The `*` matches any string (zero or more characters).

If you want to only match directory names that should not start and end with a hyphen (as in your example), you could use

```
[!-]*-*-*[!-]/
```

instead. The `[!-]` matches any character that is not (`!`) a hyphen.

Run

```
ls -d [!-]*-*-*[!-]/
```

first to see if these are the ones you want to delete. Then run

```
rm -r [!-]*-*-*[!-]/
```

to delete them recursively. If you should really need to force the deletion, add `-f` to the command.

Comment: The _standard_ way of saying "not a dash" is `[!-]`, but `bash` accepts `[^-]` too.

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda, edited.

Answer (score 5):

```
rm -r *-*-*-*-*
```

WARNING: This will remove every file that matches to this scheme. So files like:

```
system-file-separated-by-minus
```

will be deleted too.

The '*' part stands for everything (zero, one or multiple characters) until the next given, in this case separated by minus. If you know your files have
8 characters in front of the -, 4 in front of the next you can say:

```
rm -r ????????-????-????-????-????????????
```

Every ? stands for any character.
This would remove all files matching your scheme. But also files that have the same scheme will be deleted that you might not want, so check this first.

Comment: Is the null string important in this case? If yes for what?

Answer (score 3):

Simply execute this command in the parent directory

```
rm -r *-*-*/
```